# Two questions about backing up your website (mysql and files)

Tags: mysql, backup, database-backups

So the only method i like using  and think is the simplest to use is mysqldump to backup mysql databases. Right now, im using phpmyadmin to backup the tables. Is there any way i can code a script that does it automatically (preferably everyday).

And how do i back up files exactly on my server. I have an images file that i need to back up. I'm not sure exactly how to go about backing those up.

Comment: Cronjobs with aa `mysqldump` are certainly possible, but I like the continuous backup by replication. For files an `rsync` backup. But you really should ask this on ServerFault rather then StackOverflow.

Comment: @Wrikken: personally, I *think* this is more for [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/): "for professional and enthusiast webmasters. If your question generally covers the operation of websites which you control..." rather than [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/): "for system administrators and desktop support professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity."

Comment: never heard of serverfault before, its just came into my attention. thanks

Comment: @David: backing up would be a sysadmin duty where I come from, the fact the data is from a website doesn't come in to play IMHO (backing up databases & files from any server with any task is largely the same). But there is some overlap indeed.

Comment: @Wrikken, Serverfault seems to be targeted to sysadmins and other professionals (and, without trying to be offensive, this question suggests that Ben isn't a pro sysadmin) than anything else, whereas Webmasters seems less 'professional-oriented.' ...great, now I feel like I've managed to offend two whole communities, and Ben, accidentally... =/

Comment: Both ServerFault & StackOVerflow are targeted at beginners, professionals, experts and everything in between. 'Starting out' a sysadmin duty, or just wondering what the best way would be to do a certain sysadmin task, seems to me an excellent reason to ask experts a question. There is nothing at ServerFault that says you have to be experienced to join, far from it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course -- use [`MySQL Dumper`](http://www.mysqldumper.net/). You can automatically backup your databases to another host if you like!

**Features**

- **Send dumpfiles via FTP** to up to 3 different server. This is also working using the multipart feature.
- **Automatic file-deletion:** set your own rules to delete old backups. Specify the number of backups you want to hold and let MySQLDumper automatically delete the older ones to save server webspace.
- **MySQLDumper can do Multipart-Backups.** That means: it can automatically split the dumpfile if it gets bigger than your chosen size. When you want to restore a backup and choose the wrong part - it doesn' matter: MySQLDumper will notice that and will get the correct startfile automatically.
- **Security:** MySQLDumper can generate a .htaccess-file to protect itself and all of your backup-files

---

**Good reading resource for alternatives**

- [10 Ways to Automatically & Manually Backup MySQL Database](http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since Gary answered your first question, I'll answer your second.

For backing up the server:

I'm assuming you are talking about your web applications and the images contained in folders used by those applications.  Source control will work for this.  Set up a Subversion server or something like it.

http://subversion.tigris.org/

Hope this helps.  Good luck.